# win32 c++ owner draw button with transparent image

Tags: c++, winapi, button, transparency, ownerdrawn

i've implemented a owner draw button into my win32 app (no MFC). The button is a normal 20x20 bitmap (round icon with transparency). The problem is that the button is positioned on a solid background and i can see the buttons gray background (since the bitmap is round). I've tried responding to WM_CTLCOLORBTN with NULL_BRUSH but no luck.. I've tried displaying the button using a bitmap and a ico file but wont budge.. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is my problem, the settings icon should be transparent at the edges (not white/gray)

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Make a completely invisible button?

Comment: no it's a settings button.. and since it's a round icon i can see the gray background at the edges.

Comment: It is very unclear, but it sounds like you got what you asked for.  The image is transparent against the *button's* background.  If you actually want to make it transparent against the *parent's* background then you need to wrangle the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style bit.

Comment: added a screenshot to clear what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @joel's answer, if you want to make some area transperant put a unique color in the area where you want to have transperancy using some image editors (RGB(0xFF,0x00,0xFF)) is mostly used Then use [TransperantBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Using the transparnetBlt function didn't work (still had to remove the default button background). so i've combined TransparentBlt and returned a hollow_brush on WM_CTLCOLORBTN message, which did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to make a non-rectangular control.

You could call [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28VS.85%29.aspx) to tell Windows that your control is non-rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

You say it's a solid background but your image shows some kind of orange-yellow gradient as a background.  If it really was a standard windows button solid color you can load the bitmap with LoadImage using the LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS or LR_LOADTRANSPARENT.  Since you have a gradient you'll have to use a more complicated technique to mask out the bitmap.
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html